# iOS Auto-Layout Max-Width

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, constraints

So I'm trying to build a view that obeys the following. On smaller screens, the view will match the trailing and leading constraints to consume 100% of the width excluding the 32px margin. On larger screens, the view will not exceed a width of some constant, let's say 480px.

I've looked into it, and I tried setting the trailing and leading constraints to have a lower priority than the `<=` width constraint, however, on screens smaller than 480 pixels for example, the view will expand beyond the bounds of the screen. Essentially, I'm trying to use auto layout to use 100% width with 32px margin up to 480px. How do I fix my constraints?

Comment: Can you set priority for trailing/leading higher than width, and make width = 480 (instead of <=)?

Comment: Look at this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50557236/1630618)

Comment: @vacawama As I've explained, that's exactly the technique I tried but for whatever reason it's not working.

Comment: Did you center the view?  That is key.

Comment: Yes I did, and the priority of that constraint is 1000

Comment: I just tried changing the leading and trailing to 999, and it worked. It was 750 before, but I'm not really sure what's the difference here

Comment: Perhaps its related to the contents of your view and their constraints.

Comment: My content is a single button. I'm not sure why centering (1000) and width (1000) worked with leading and trailing 999 instead of 750

Comment: I think its because the Content Compression of the button also has a priority of `750`.  So AutoLayout doesn't know if it should compress the button or make the margins `32`.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I wish there was some documentation regarding this. If you must know I have a stack view with my logo and login button with some separation. The stack view is centered and constrained with these margins. Maybe the same applies